# Pointer to vector of pointers to vectors

Tags: c++, vector

what do I wrong?

```
vector<vector<unsigned int> *> *matrix
matrix = new vector<vector<unsigned int> *>(n);
for (vector<vector<unsigned int> *>::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    matrix->at(i) = new vector<unsigned int>(i + 1);
}

...
```

The code

```
vector<int> *myVector2 = new vector<int>(500000000);
for(size_t i = 0; i < myVector->size(); i++) {
    myVector->at(i) = i;
}
delete myVector;
```

works fine. I need to work with a very large matrix - so large that it is impossible save the whole matrix and I need to change the memory usage dynamically (sometimes to store only some rows, not all rows are full (I need to see only k first elements of them) etc.).

Comment: There is not much point in storing a `vector` of pointers to `vector`. `std::vector` isn't that much bigger than a pointer, usually only about 3 pointers in size. So you're not gaining much memory by only storing pointers to `vector`s

Comment: Also, what error are you getting? And stop putting your signature back in your post. We can see your name just fine in the box just to the right of the question.

Comment: Well… the `vector`s still exist even if you *also* store pointers to them. So really this is storing both, and the problem (efficiency wise) is storing and indirecting through unnecessary pointers.

Comment: It is true, but the if I watched on the second example the memory usage, I was able really to free the memory by deleting the vector. And I need to do it for the vector members.

Comment: I.e. to have once 2 * 250000000 long rows and then only one row with 500000000 numbers.

Comment: The error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector< int>*>*’ in assignment

Answer (score 2):

`new` is probably not helping anything here. The main purpose of `vector` is to take care of calling `new` for you.

```
typedef vector<vector<unsigned int> > matrix_t;
matrix_t matrix( n );
std::size_t row_index = 0;
for ( matrix_t::iterator i = matrix.begin(); i != matrix.end(); ++ i ) {
    i.resize( row_index + 1 );
    ++ row_index;
}
```

When you want to change the number or length of rows, call `matrix.resize()` or `matrix[n].resize()`. This minimizes the number of allocations. But it might be better to map everything to a single, flat vector which is as big as the largest matrix you will need. Freeing and reallocating things on the fly causes various inefficiencies such as unnecessary cache misses and VM paging.

**Edit:** When making a vector smaller with `resize`, its memory is usually not freed. You need to use a trick:

```
std::vector< unsigned int >( new_row_length ).swap( v );
```

Note, this only helps when making a vector much smaller; when making it larger or the change is small, it's better to stick to `resize`.

The best solution is probably to find an existing linear algebra library and use an existing triangular matrix class.

Comment: I tryed this showed way by a simple vector but if I show the memory usage via top (in Linux), the resize command can improve the memory usage but not decrease.

Comment: Yes, but my matrix will not be triangular for the whole program. I need to have then also some shorter and some longer rows (it is problem of graph theory and adjacency lists)

Comment: @qwertzuiop: To shorten a row use: `std::vector<int>().swap(matrix[12]);`

Comment: @qwertzuiop D'oh, I was writing the same advice as Loki. But the best practice in this kind of situation is to avoid coding too low-level at first. At least look for a library with high-level (e.g. matrix multiplication) operations that you can synthesize the algorithm from. Otherwise find one that will give you a flat representation of the kinds of matrices you need, and then allocate/deallocate those huge flat vectors instead of trying to transform a vector of smaller vectors.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will try to find something high-level for my purpouse.